# mysql update INSERT INTO code

Tags: mysql

I have 2 accounts with the same hosting company but on different servers.  I have been using this code on both for different data for some time.  The data comes from a webform.  MySQL was updated recently on one of the servers and the code stopped working.  event_id field is set to auto-increment

$query = "INSERT INTO table (event_id, event_date, event_time, event_title, event_code, event_content)
VALUES ('', '$event_date', '$event_time', '$event_title', '$event_code', '$event_content')";

I changed the code by removing the event_id from the first line and '', from the second as below and it now works

$query = "INSERT INTO table (event_date, event_time, event_title, event_code, event_content)
VALUES ('$event_date', '$event_time', '$event_title', '$event_code', '$event_content')";

I really want to ask whether this is the effect of the MySQL upgrade or something else.  I don't really know about coding so it is all trial and error using bits that have been written for me.

Margaret

Comment: Not part of your question, but your code is *very* dangerous. It has what is called an SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Thank you, Daniel, for pointing this out.  We have added 'mysql_real_escape_string' into the code which I hope is the correct thing to do.  Margaret

Comment: That is the start of the correct thing.  The "best" approach is to use prepared statements and the a modern client code (mysqli or PDO MySQL)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple: you cannot set a value to `auto-increment` field :)